# Cannot Configure kerio-control-vpnclient in ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: dpkg

I have a problem with configuring kerio-control-vpnclient in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

this command must work for me. the output says it is not installed. But it is installed:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure kerio-control-vpnclient
Package `kerio-control-vpnclient' is not installed and no info is available.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: kerio-control-vpnclient is not installed
```

First time I install kerio-control-vpnclient it starts configuration wizard and I set it up. But after that I cannot config it again with the command that it offers for reconfiguration.

I still can start stop restart kerio and it is on my system but dpkg-reconfigure cannot find it. I think it is because of 64bit system. I try to add i386 arch with this command:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'foreign-architecture i386' > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch"
```

But still nothing.

Comment: What was the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep kerio`?

Comment: Thank you. the output was the answer. I must add :i386 to the end of the command. I must ask it sooner instead of wasting a lot of my time. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As op said, the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep kerio` command shows,

```
kerio-control-vpnclient:i386
```

So reconfiguring the above package will works,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure kerio-control-vpnclient:i386
```